# jQuery UI tooltip to data-title

Tags: jquery-ui-tooltip

I'm trying to change the default [title] usage from jQuery UI tooltip to [data-title].

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(document).tooltip({
            track: true,
            items: "[data-title]",
            content: function () {
                return ( ( $( this ).prop( 'data-title' ).replace( '|', '<br />' ) ) );
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<span class="class blade" data-title="Tooltip title"></span>
```

This works perfectly if I remove the data-, but with it nothing displays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) api to read the `data-*` attribute

```
$(function () {
    $(document).tooltip({
        track: true,
        items: "[data-title]",
        content: function () {
            return $(this).data('title').replace('|', '<br />');
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bYzm9/)

Answer (score 1):

Do not use [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) in these circumstances.

You are trying to fetch the value of an *HTML attribute*, not a *DOM property*, so use [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) instead:

```
return $(this).attr("data-title").replace("|", "<br />");
```

`data-` attributes, unlike most other HTML attributes, do not have DOM property equivalents.